# Windows Phone 8 Hanging on GetFolderAsync and OpenStreamForReadAsync

Tags: asynchronous, windows-phone-8, io

I am making a windows phone 8 application.  Part of this application requires state to be saved. I am saving it as a string of Json.  If I open the application, save some data, exit the application and the load it again, it hangs on either GetFolderAsync or OpenStreamForReadAsync. It does not happen every time, but once it starts hanging, I have to kill the whole emulator and make a new one to start the application again.

I have even tried just making an empty file with no data in it and the problem still persistes.

Below is the code I am using to save and load the data.  It does not matter where I call the data load whether it be on application start or on the form load it still breaks.

```
    private async Task SaveLists()
    {
        //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListHolder));

        // Get the local folder.
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        // Create a new folder name DataFolder.
        var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder",
            CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        // Create a new file named DataFile.txt.
        var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("Lists.json",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Lists, Formatting.Indented);
        byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json.ToCharArray());

        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

        }
    }



    private async Task LoadLists()
    {


        // Get the local folder.
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        if (local != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the DataFolder folder.

                var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("DataFolder");

                // Get the file.
                var files = dataFolder.GetFilesAsync();
                var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Lists.json");

                string jsonString = "";
                // Read the data.
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                if (jsonString.Length > 0)
                {
                    Lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemList>>(jsonString);
                }    
                else
                {
                    Lists = new List<ItemList>();
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Lists = new List<ItemList>();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if the folder really exists and contains the data you expect it to contain? (I mean, by hand, not programmatically.)

Comment: @Richard - How are you calling your functions? 1) `await LoadLists()`, or 2) `LoadLists().Wait()`?

Comment: I am calling is like this: 
await LoadLists();

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see if the folders and files actually exist as they are on a phone as part of the app.  Is there some way to actually see them without code?  I did call GetFoldersAsync and I could see the folder in the Quickwatch window

Comment: @RichardMannion: Do you have a `Wait` or `Result` *anywhere* in your calling stack? Or is it all started with an `async void` event handler?

Comment: @StephenCleary The call stack for this starts with 

` private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)`
        
It then calls a 
async Task<State> LoadState()

but it calls it without an await and that method then calls the LoadLists() and other methods for loading the applications state

So the call stack is essentially
`Application_Launching...
ApplicationState = controller.LoadState().Result;
await LoadLists();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are causing a deadlock by calling `Result`. I explain this deadlock [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In summary, `await` will (by default) attempt to resume execution within a context (the current `SynchronizationContext` unless it is `null`, in which case it uses the current `TaskScheduler`).

In your case, the current `SynchronizationContext` is the UI context, which is only used by the UI thread. So when you block the UI thread by calling `Result`, the `async` method cannot schedule back to the UI thread to complete.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to have solve the issue.  There are still timing issues between loading the data and when the GUI actually loads but that should be solvable. I will read your blog thanks.

Comment: For that, I recommend you purposefully design a "loading" state for your UI, have your initial load start in that state, and transition state when the data loads. If you use MVVM, I wrote a [`NotifyTaskCompletion` type](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion) that essentially allows you to data-bind to `Task` results (and get `INotifyPropertyChanged` events when the `Task` completes).